# "Reminiscent Hawaii" technical meaning

Tags: subjects, objects, agent-nouns

> 1 "Reminiscent Hawaii" - caption on photo
>
> 2 "The Na Pali Coast is a reminiscent place!" - verbal

**Would these technically mean the place inspires reminiscing?** (of free agents)

**Or would it literally mean the place itself has some sort of agency of its own and is reminiscing?** (as if the place was literally a person/free agent)

Comment: What makes you think that is a permissible collocation? No native speaker would ever use *reminiscent* to mean *memorable*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an uncommon, possibly figurative,  usage; the construction is "reminiscent of":

According to the Oxford Collocation Dictionary: ***[reminiscent](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=reminiscent)***: (verb: be/preposition:  of):

> - ADV. closely, highly, strongly, very - *This painting is strongly reminiscent of da Vinci's ‘Annunciation’.*  | faintly, slightly, somewhat | curiously, strangely | strikingly | irresistibly

Comment: That makes sense. I think reminiscent "of X" is more clear, but I would prefer to leave this out as my situation calls for being non-specific. I will probably use "of many things" to avoid the confusion because Hawaii in my story is actually both the island and a distinct character.